# Element is restricted to 390px, but on ios safari and chrome the web page opens with a way wider width

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile

The css is as such

```
#element{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 390px; width: 100%;
}
```

The element is inside the body tag, the width is 100%0 so if for some reason the screen is smaller it should adjust, and on desktop the page should stay at 390px. This works on desktop but when i open the web page on my iphone not only does it not restrict to 390px, but it expands a lot wider. I know that it isnt simply zooming in because all the proportions are off.

I have tried changing the viewport tag, specifying the width restriction in the css with a @ media screen, Every time i test it within google chromes dev emulator it looks great but when i actually deploy the website and open it on my phone its blown up. When i open the site on desktop its restricted to the 390px just like i want it to be. This problem only occurs on mobile browsers, ive used both chrome and safari, on my iphone and it doesnt work. Also i'll add that the site is properly sized on all browsers on both pc and mac.

im not sure what else to try pls hlp lol

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out but it wasn't easy. The engine that processes css on mobile safari and chrome engine process the css differently than on desktop. I had to open a live server through vscode, and open the live server on my phone to see how it looks rather than using the google chrome emulator. Than I had to go through each element on the css file and adjust whatever element looked off. As I did this the website looked better on my phone but worst on the engine, all the way up until i finished in which it came together on both. The thing i needed to fix was mainly the aspect ratio. I had an element set with an aspect ration incorrectly which was ignored on google chromes emulator but messed up the actual page on mobile. To any one developing anything for mobile i recommend opening the live server on an actual phone or tablet rather than using the windows emulator, or preferably use both

Comment: You might wanna look into CSS media queries which were invented for exactly this purpose: Having different styles apply to different devices. And yes, always check on your phone, but if you write correct code, you'll have no problems using Chromes responsive view to get the same result. Another tipp: You probably would have found this error way faster by adding overflow:hidden to your #element and check for the overlapping content causing this.